# How to remove the <a> tags only from a text?

Tags: java, regex

Greetings all,
I have a text that may contains the `<a></a>` tags something like :

```
hello this is a link <a href="www.google.com"> www.google.com </a> please visit it.
```

I want to remove those tags and keep the text between them
to be like:

```
hello this is a link  www.google.com  please visit it.
```

, how to do ?

Comment: Are you talking about HTML tags, like `<a href="http://example.com">A link</a>`, or about something else?

Comment: yup exactly what um talking about.

Comment: @Jean - if he's talking about html tags, the text between the tags is *not* the address (url) - that is, as we probably all know, the value of the `href` attribute.. so yes, what exactly shall be "kept"??

Comment: I want to keep what is between the < a > tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String str="<a>sadasd</a>";
str.replaceAll("<a>","").replaceAll("</a>","");//sadasd
```

Or

```
 str.replaceAll("</?a>","");//sadasd
```

Or the best way is to go for [Jsoup Cleaner](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer)

```
        String str = "hello this is a link <a href='www.google.com'> www.google.com </a> please visit it";
        String safe = Jsoup.clean(str, Whitelist.simpleText());
        System.out.println(safe);//hello this is a link  www.google.com  please visit it
```

Comment: sorry but it didn't work with a large text like : please visit this link http://www.google.com

Comment: for large html parsing you should go for JSoup

Comment: @sword can you please update your question with your problem , I doubt you aren't parsing huge html

Comment: `hello this is a link  www.google.com  please visit it.` I don't see any `<a>` tag here

Comment: the tags is in the first text, and i want to parse the first text to be like the second.

Comment: in the prior solution we were replacing occurance of <a> and </a> with blank string , while now we have used Jsoup Cleaner it is nice way to escape such HTML , check update

Answer (score 9):

For just the `<a>` and `</a>` tags

```
String source = "<a>blargle</a>";
source.replaceAll( "</?a>", "" );
```

If you mean `<a>` tags with other attributes then you would need

```
String source = "<a>blargle</a>";
source.replaceAll( "</?a[^>]*>", "" );
```

Comment: exactly If there's an < a > tag with or without attributes, remove all the tags with atributes and keep the text between them.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: `str.replaceAll("</?a>","")`

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("</?a>", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (message.contains("<a href=")) {
    message = message.replaceAll("(.*)?<a.*?>", "").replaceAll("</a>", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it is a bad idea to fix HTML with a regular expression - for a discussion see the top answer here [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)  - even though it looks like it might just be quick .  Try instead to use a DOM parser in your language of choice and just replace the  node with its child text node.