# Java Regex to get the text from HTML anchor (<a>...</a>) tags

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get a text within a certain tag. So if I have:

```
<a href="http://something.com">Found<a/>
```

I want to be able to retrieve the `Found` text.

I'm trying to do it using regex. I am able to do it if the `<a href="http://something.com>` stays the same but it doesn't.

So far I have this:

```
Pattern titleFinder = Pattern.compile( ".*[a-zA-Z0-9 ]* ([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)</a>.*" );
```

I think the last two parts - the `([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)</a>.*` - are ok but I don't know what to do for the first part.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).  Use a proper XML/HTML parser...

Comment: thanks for the reply, ill look into it =D but im not doing it for a lot of html tags its only for this one tag which occurs 15 times...is that still bad?

Comment: Java’s regexes are not powerful enough to parse HTML; other languages’, however, are.  Why anyone in their right mind would use Java for regex work is utterly beyond me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As they said, don't use regex to parse HTML. If you are aware of the shortcomings, you might get away with it, though. Try

```
Pattern titleFinder = Pattern.compile("<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher regexMatcher = titleFinder.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    // matched text: regexMatcher.group(1)
}
```

will iterate over all matches in a string.

It won't handle nested `<a>` tags and ignores all the attributes inside the tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replaceAll("</?a>", "");
```

Here is [**online ideone demo**](http://ideone.com/Lwgfg)

Here is similar topic : [How to remove the  tags only from a text ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614567/how-to-remove-the-a-tags-only-from-a-text)

Comment: This ignores the `href` and any other attributes.